# Insert a node at a specific position in a linked list JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
public static SinglyLinkedListNode insertNodeAtPosition(SinglyLinkedListNode llist, int data, int position) {
    if(llist == null) {
        llist =  new SinglyLinkedListNode(data);
        return llist;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < position-1; i++) {
            llist = llist.next;
        }
        SinglyLinkedListNode temp = llist;
        llist.next = new SinglyLinkedListNode(data);
        llist = llist.next;
        llist.next = temp.next;         
        return llist;
    }
}
```

This is my code to place a custom index node in LinkedList. But hackerrank is not accepting my code. What's wrong with my algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code always returns the newly created node, but you should always return the *first* node in the list, which either is what it was when you got it, or is the new node in case the position was zero.

#### What to look at:

I'll not provide the corrected code, but will give you two hints:

By moving `llist` ahead in the `for` loop, you lose the reference to that first node, so use a different variable for walking through the list.

Also, you should deal specifically with the case where `position` is 0, as this is the only case where the returned value is not the original `llist` value, but the new node's reference, much like you have in the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution No need of explaination :
Solution :

```
static SinglyLinkedListNode insertNodeAtPosition(SinglyLinkedListNode head, int data, int position) {
        if (head == null) return null;
        SinglyLinkedListNode temp = new SinglyLinkedListNode(data);
        if (position == 0) {
            temp.next = head;
            return temp;
        }
        SinglyLinkedListNode p = head;
        for (int i = 0; i< position-1; i++) {
            p = p.next;
        }
        SinglyLinkedListNode next = p.next;
        p.next = temp;
        temp.next = next;
        return head;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem requires you to return a linked list. When we are asked to return a linked list, actually we return the first node of the linked list.

So, your problem is the returned value in your code script is not the first node of the linked list.

The simplest solution is that you keep the first node in another variable, and
return that variable after you have done the insert thing.
for example:

```
SinglyLinkedListNode dumyNode = llist;
......
return dumyNode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose given the correct Node class, you can try this approach (without index collision case):

```
private Node find(int index) {
    Node curr = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        curr = curr.next;

    return curr;
}   // end find()

public Object get(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if (index >= 0 && index < size) {
        Node curr = find(index);
        return curr.data;
    } else {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }   // end if - else
}   // end get()

public void add(Object data, int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if (index >= 0 && index < size + 1) {
        if (index == 0)
            head = new Node(data);
        else {
            Node prev = find(index - 1);
            prev.next = new Node(data);
        } // end if - else
        size++;
    } else {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }   // end if - else
}   // end add()
```